# Qt - Changing QTableWidget's Data to another class's QTableWidget's Data

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I'm have two , one on a MainWindow ui and another on a Dialog ui. What I'm trying to do is copy the data from the Dialog's  and paste it in the MainWindow's . What I have tried to do is use Qt's Slot's and Signals mechanism to copy the data. Below is the code I tried to use:

MainWindow.h:

```
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:   
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);


~MainWindow();

public slots:
void SetTableDataSlot(QTableWidgetItem* EditData);
}
```

MainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "dialog.h"
Dialog *dialog;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
dialog = new Dialog(this);
connect(mEdit,SIGNAL(setTableDataSignal(QTableWidgetItem*)),
                 this,SLOT(setTableDataSlot(QTableWidgetItem*)));
dialog->show();
}

void MainWindow::setTableDataSlot(QTableWidgetItem* EditData){
for(int i = 0; i<ui->tableWidget->rowCount();++i){
    for(int j = 0; j<ui->tableWidget->columnCount();++j){
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,j,EditData->clone());
    }
  }
}
```

Dialog.h:

```
#include <QDialog>
#include <QTableWidget>


namespace Ui {
class dialog;
}

class dialog : public QDialog
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);

~dialog();
signals:
void setTableDataSignal(QTableWidgetItem *EditData);
}
```

Dialog.cpp:

```
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "editmode1.h"
#include "ui_editmode1.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
delete ui;
}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
for (int i=0; i<rows;++i){
    for(int j = 0; j<columns;++j){
        emit setTableDataSignal(ui->tableWidget->item(i,j);
    }
  }
}
```

Now the program compiles fine but when I click on the button on the dialog form, it copies the data from the last cell in the dialog table, and pastes it in every cell in the mainwindow table. If anyone can give me an explanation on what is wrong here and how it could be fixed I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: start from explaining what exactly you are trying to achieve. I can see description "it doesn't work like I want" but only shreds of information what do you want.

Comment: sorry, I thought I put it well. It does also say what I want in the title, I'm sorry but I don't much agree with your statement, please point out where I could improve and I'll be happy to do so, thanks!

Comment: should both widgets show exactly same information winch is in sync? In such case passing whole data model will solve problem perfectly in one simple line.

Comment: both widgets should show the same information when the button is clicked. how exactly do I solve this in a single line? thanks.

Comment: `widgetB->setModel(widgetA->model());`

Comment: would this mean setting the tablewidget's to a model and then transferring the model using a signal and switch mechanism? is that right? I'm not sure if this is what you mean.

Comment: also qtablewidget doesnt allow me to set a model, i would then have to use qtableview and this would mean changing more code, so preferabbly not, is it somehow possible to use setModel on a qtablewidget.

Comment: Nope. Simply data model will be shared. Every change done by view will update a model and every model which uses this model will display up to date values of given model. This is standard MVC pattern. Difference between QTableView and QTableWidget is only that Widget version enforces use of standard item model. So you can safely switch to QTableView if you need to.

Comment: so how do i do this with a tablewidget? I'm not sure what you mean sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in this line:

```
ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,j,&EditData);
```

You pass a pointer of an object that live in the stack and will be destroyed at the end of the `setTableDataSlot`. Also you are trying to set the same object in all the table cells.

You have to create a new `QTableWidgetItem` for each cell.

Also the logic is wrong, because you are copying each cell of table A end put each copy into all cells of table B (cell [0, 0] of A in all cells of B, than cell [0, 1] of A in all cells of B and so on).

I suggest to change approach (for example get the table of the dialog from the main window and copy the cells, without passing all the QTableWidgetItem by signal-slot)

EDIT

You can use this function to copy the QTableItems from a table to another (not tested)

```
void copyTableContents(QTableWidget* sourceTable, QTableWidget* destTable)
{
    for(int r = 0; r < sourceTable->rowCount() && r < destTable->rowCount(); ++r)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < sourceTable->columnCount() && c < destTable->columnCount(); ++c)
        {
            //delete old item if exists
            QTableWidgetItem* dItem = destTable->takeItem(r, c);
            if(dItem)
                delete dItem;
            QTableWidgetItem* sItem = sourceTable->item(r, c);
            if(sItem) //copy the item if exists
                destTable->setItem(r, c, sItem->clone());
        }
    }
}
```

You can create a function in the dialog that return the table pointer.
You can emit a signal without parameters from dialog when the copy button is clicked.
Connect this signal to a slot of the main window that get the table from the dialog and call the function to copy the items.

Comment: I get a SIGSEGV error but now on the line `ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,j, EditData->clone());`.

Comment: Maybe some cell are NULL. And now I see that also the logic is totally wrong.

Comment: I'm not to great with qt, how exactly would I copy the cells from the dialog screen? That is what I'm trying to do but I don't know how to without getting sigsegv error, please help. Thanks for pointing out the error in the logic though.

Comment: The sigsegv error is probably caused by a C++ error in the code. I need more code to investigate (e.g I don't understand the role of the EditMode1 class and how the table in the dialog is created). Also you must check that the QTableWidgetItem returned by the item() method is not NULL.

Comment: what more do you need to see (the editmode bit I have edited out, its not needed here (this entire code is ripped out of a bigger chunk of code as you have guessed by now)), I simply made the tables by dragging them in on the qt form designer and editing them in the constructors respectively, using functions like setRowCount and setColumnCount to create the appropriate table sizes.

Comment: For example the variable `TableWidgetedit` in the`Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()` is very strange. I expected to see a **pointer** to a table, and specifically someting like `ui->tableWidget->item(i,j)` if you have created the table with the designer

Comment: `tablewidgetedit` is simply a pointer to `EditUi->tableWidget`, replacing allows me to run the program, however now when i click on the pushbutton, it transfers (0,0) on the dialog table and places it in all spaces on the mainwindow table. so this is probably the logical error you were on about. any clue what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Sorry but TableWidgetedit can't be a pointer (TableWidgetedit.item(i,j) instead of TableWidgetedit->item(i,j)).

Comment: ok that explains a fair bit a few errors I had haha, thank you. onto the new problem, which is now that it copies the last cell in the dialog table and places it in all of the cells in the mainwindow table, and I understand this logical error (sort of) but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: As general rule **never** use deference operator with Qt objects. I have written a function and some suggestions, see my edits